# How to pass parameters in jquery for a user defined function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write a user defined function using jQuery to swap two div tags within the page. I created the function but it is not swapping them as desired. In fact, when I move the same code inline it works fine. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Debugging invisible code is considerably harder than debugging visible code. To that end, could you show yours?

Comment: Please post the code and markup you're using.

Comment: *Is there something I am missing?* **teh codez...**

Comment: Sorry. I initially thought I had copied and pasted it.

Comment: .. and still you do not add it to your question (*you can edit it, and add it..*)

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to debug something that I cannot see, but I wrote a "swapper function" for you:

```
function swapem($el1, $el2) {
    var $t=$el2.clone().insertAfter($el1);
    $el1.insertAfter($el2);
    $el2.remove();
}

$('#swapper').click(function () {
    swapem($('#div1'), $('#div2'));
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/jn2vc/)

Comment: @user792967 If you are satisfied with it, please click the tickmark on the left of the answer to accept it.